# Sort Sets in ArrayList by Size

Tags: java, sorting, set

I thought of doing this by putting all of the sets in a list that would then be in a map, where the key is the size. I know the maximum size that a set could be(given to me), so I can just iterate between 0 and that number, get each list and then iterate through each list and put each set in an arraylist.

However, this seems horrifically clunky - is there a better way of doing this? Is there some way I can do a comparator function based on size?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can provide a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for that. and use `Collections.sort()`

```
class SizeComarator implements Comparator<Set<?>> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Set<?> o1, Set<?> o2) {
        return Integer.valueOf(o1.size()).compareTo(o2.size());
    }
}

    ArrayList<Set<String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<Set<String>>();
    Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<String>();
    set1.add("A");
    set1.add("B");
    Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<String>();
    set2.add("A");
    arrayList.add(set1);
    arrayList.add(set2);
    Collections.sort(arrayList, new SizeComarator());
    System.out.println(arrayList);
```

Output:

```
 [[A], [A, B]]
```

Comment: hmm so the thing that I'm sorting is really an object that is implemented as a private class - does this method still apply?

Comment: @praks5432 Added some more code so it will be easy for you to understand :)

Comment: Beware of this implementation. I suspect that returning the same size to e.g. a `TreeSet<>#add()` will result to items being considered the same and dropped.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other (perfectly valid) answer, I'll just point out that you don't need to explicitly define a new class, you can just create one anonymously:

```
Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<Set<?>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Set<?> o1, Set<?> o2) {
        return Integer.valueOf(o1.size()).compareTo(o2.size());
    }
});
```

Of couse, if you plan on using such a comparator multiple times, then I would consider defining it explicitly.

---

Relevant javadocs:

- [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)